# Update bulk data using Sequelize mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to update data over 100k but i am unable to update it. I am using Sequalize and mysql.
I am first reading data from the .txt file then update the table data against the data already available in the table.
I am using Sequalize but it takes over 1 hour to update 100k records.
Is any way to update bulk data using Sequalize?

This is my sample code:

```
async.each(arrayData, function(_arrayData, _callback) {
        var connection = index.connection;
   let query = 'UPDATE debit_tran_reg SET response_status ='+'"'+_arrayData.response_status+'"'+',response_rejection_reason='+'"'+_arrayData.response_rejection_reason+'"'+',umrn_no='+'"'+_arrayData.umrn_no+'"'+'WHERE loan_no ='+'"'+_arrayData.loan_no+'"'+'';
          connection.query(query).spread((results, metadata) => { 
            console.log("results> "+JSON.stringify(results));
          });
          _callback();
      },function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log("*****ALL DATA HAS BEEN PROCESSED*****")
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try formulating the query for the entire data and then running it as one query as opposed to multiple individual queries, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to these options:

I see now that you run a different query for each row. First thing I would do is to collect them all in a single query statement and run it only once.
Something like this (i would use a query builder that protects you from possibile injection):

```
var array = [
    {id: 1, val:10}
  {id: 2, val:15}
];

console.log(array.reduce((s,v)=> s+"update table set col1="+v.val+" where id="+v.id+";", ""))
```

and then run in a transaction.

You could also try to "simulate" the update operation with a DELETE and INSERT inside a transaction. Bulk insert sounds like way faster than multiple updates.

**EDIT**: add s+ to the reduce function

Comment: i am updating each record for multiple values within async like _arrayData.response_status which is the dynamic value.

Comment: Bulk insert is working good for insert but i want to update a bulk record which is dynamic value

Comment: yeah, but I was thinking that if you have a lot of rows, maybe it is worth to delete+insert the updated ones (so basically you are "simulating" an update) instead of running update multiple times.

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks a ton!....Can You suggest me the query for Sequelize or Mysql raw query, it would be really helpful.

Comment: In this case I think I would go plain sql. I would just use a tool to buil the queries to avoid injection. Check this: http://knexjs.org/

Comment: anywyay, I would still give a try to a delete + bulk insert.